# Google Maps custom pins failing to appear on some browsers on different PCs

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I've built a map using the GMaps API with custom markers. On my PC (Chrome and Firefox) it looks correct, like this:

[image]

But on my colleagues PC with exactly the same versions of the same browsers and on the same network it looks like this:

[image]

In addition, on my Mac in Opera it also looks like the second image.

Has anyone run into this issue before? And is there a fix?

URL: http://archer.jacksleight.com/map

Comment: Can you post url to check in our machines?

Comment: Sorry, that would help: http://archer.jacksleight.com/map

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, Marker path is not correct. Once check in firebug.Path is showing as

localhost/archers/assets/images/icon.png

But actual path is

http://archer.jacksleight.com/assets/images/icon.png

**Checked in Firebug:**

[image]

Comment: Ah! You're absolutely right. That explains why it works for me (I have the site locally). Thanks!